# Winsock tracing can't get verbose level events

Tags: windows, winsock2, netsh, etw

while it's very easy to get info level tracing started with Windows-Winsock-AFD using:
netsh trace start provider=Microsoft-Windows-Winsock-AFD TraceFile=my_
winsock_log3_trace.etl

the file generated seems to not include verbose level events such as "Select/Poll Posted".
I've also tried: "netsh trace start provider=Microsoft-Windows-Winsock-AFD TraceFile=my_winsock_log3_trace.etl level=5" didn't help (same level events)

Has anyone been able to start winsock tracing at verbose?

Thanks